# ui-router controller instantiated again on ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a state A with a link to a state B.
State A's controller contains some method declarations and calls on $scope. So something like:

```
controller : function($scope) {
  $scope.myFunc = { ... }
  $scope.myFunc();
}
```

When going to state B, the function $scope.myFunc() is called again. Why is it and how to avoid?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The A state contains a inner $state.go with notify and reload set to false to update parameters. If I remove this, the transition is ok...why?

**JSFIDDLE**
This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p2qnrfsm/

Comment: Please attach a fiddle with your question so that we can see the issue and help you. :)

Comment: Added the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2qnrfsm/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$state.go($state.current.name,{ value :  $scope.value }, {reload:false, notify : false})`? Since that causes your issue.

Comment: I would like to have an update on the URL without reloading the state. I can do it using search params but not with url path